# Bash: extract a part of a string, after a number

Tags: string, bash

I have a few strings like this:

```
var1="string one=3423423 and something which i don't care"
var2="another bigger string=413145 and something which i don't care"
var3="the longest string ever=23442 and something which i don't care"
```

These strings are the output of a python script (which i am not allowed to touch), and I need a way to extract the 1st part of the string, right after the number. Basically, my outputs should be:

```
"string one=3423423"
"another bigger string=413145"
"the longest string ever=23442"
```

As you can see, i can't use positions, or stuff like that, because the number and the string length are not always the same. I assume i would need to use a regex or something, but i don't really understand regexes. Can you please help with a command or something which can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use parameter expansion, for example:

```
var1="string one=3423423 and something which i don't care"
name=${var1%%=*}
value=${var1#*=}
value=${value%%[^0-9]*}
echo "$name=$value"
# prints: string one=3423423
```

Explanation of `${var1%%=*}`:

- `%%` - remove the longest matching suffix
- `=` - match `=`
- `*` - match everything

Explanation of `${var1#*=}`:

- `#` - remove the shortest matching prefix
- `*` - match everything
- `=` - match `=`

Explanation of `${value%%[^0-9]*}`:

- `%%` - remove the longest matching suffix
- `[^0-9]` - match any non-digit
- `*` - match everything

To perform the same thing on more than one values easily,
you could wrap this logic into a function:

```
extract_and_print() {
    local input=$1
    local name=${input%%=*}
    local value=${input#*=}
    value=${value%%[^0-9]*}
    echo "$name=$value"
}

extract_and_print "$var1"
extract_and_print "$var2"
extract_and_print "$var3"
```

Comment: this works if my string would be
`string1="3423423 and something which i don't care"`

but my string is 

`var="string one=3423423 and something which i don't care"`

Basically, the = is inside the string, it is not the sign for assigning something to a variable.

My bad, i have to edit the 1st post :)

Comment: I am not used with asking questions, and for a new line it seems i have to press Shift + Enter instead of just Enter. Please recheck my comment, i've edited it.

Comment: i really am sorry for the mistake. This is my 2nd time i'm asking for help (usually i can make it on my own), and plus the fact that this is the 3rd day i'm working in Bash, so it's a bit difficult for me to ask good questions, cuz basically i don't really know what to ask :)

Comment: @DavidBotezatu I rewrote my answer according to match your updated question.

Comment: Thank you very much! I still have 1 more question for you: why did you do 

`value=${var1#*=}
value=${value%%[^0-9]*}`

instead of maybe 

`value=${var1#*=}
value2=${value%%[^0-9]*}`

Can you please explain? Thanks!

Comment: @DavidBotezatu if you mean why did I overwrite `value` instead of creating a new variable, because the result of `${var1#*=}` is just an intermediary value: I still need to transform it into something else, and I don't need to keep it. So I simply overwrite it with the final value that I need.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations, and for your patience with me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -oP '^.*?=\d+' inputfile
string one=3423423
another bigger string=413145
the longest string ever=23442
```

Here `-o` flag will enable `grep` to print only matching part and `-p` will enable `perl` regex in `grep`. Here `\d+` means one or more digit. So, `^.*?=\d+` means print from start of the line till you find last digit (first match).

Comment: You should probably use a non-greedy form of your RE (`^.*?=\d+`) to fully comply with the OP's requirements.

Comment: @PS. I have made a mistake in the original post: Basically i have 

`var="string one=3423423 and something which i don't care"`

and i need a command, that turns that string into 

`string one=3423423`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ shopt -s extglob

$ echo "${var1%%+([^0-9])}"
string one=3423423

$ echo "${var2%%+([^0-9])}"
another bigger string=413145

$ echo "${var3%%+([^0-9])}"
the longest string ever=23442
```

`+([^0-9])` is an extended pattern that matches one or more non-digits.
`${var%%+([^0-9])}` with `%%pattern` will remove the longest match of that pattern from the end of the variable value.

Refs: [patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching), [parameter substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)